# How to recover information from Dropbox?

Tags: data-recovery, dropbox

Well, we had an emplyee who used to store all of his business accounts in Dropbox. Now he left our company turned off the sync and uninstalled dropbox so all of his files went poof! His Dropbox account was not registered to his work email so we can't access the account. Now, we all are trying to recover those files, we tried Pandora Recovery but no success.

What are our options to get this information back? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would first contact the employee and request they provide you access to this account if it contains work product. Your options are limited if the data has already been overwritten with data. Unless you went to straight to a recovery mode, the data could be gone, recovery software is all designed in similar ways.  The important thing at this point is to pull the hdd from the machine, and do not write a single bit to the hdd, otherwise you reduce the chances of recovery by several times.

Comment: Failing all else you could always start a law suit to get the files back. Dropbox has been very clear that they will never fight valid subpoenas for data that they store.

Comment: If he had dropbox installed to his local desktop, would machine or roaming profile account backups possibly contain what you are looking for?

Comment: @Ramhound, ebgreen
Yes, we are thinking about some legal action. He's neither replying to our mails nor picking our calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is really vital, and for some reason you are not able to get hold of your ex-employee, I suggest you go for professional data recovery service like [SalvageData Recovery](http://www.salvagedata.com/).
You could also try data recovery service provided by the harddrive manufacture's data recovery service. I know [Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/services-software/data-recovery-services/) does this.
If you really dont want to pay for it you could try an array of free data recovery tools like:

1. [Test Disk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
2. [Recuva](http://www.recuva.com/)
3. [Undelete Plus](http://undelete-plus.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Piriform makes a program called Recuva, I have recovered some deleted files I thought were gone. It might work for you.  In the future I would encourage(force) employees to use a network location with backup on it rather then letting them store information like that in a non-company cloud

[Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help too.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) if you get access to the Dropbox account, you might recover the files through the web-interface.

2) If your ex employee would not provide the log-in info. Then you can recover the data even if they are deleted and new data is overwritten on the old ones. However, the digital forensics may not be easy if you are new on it. Then I would strongly suggest you to contact with companies that does data-recovery, I think it would be the easiest option so that they can recover all lost file as they use good tools. It is even possible to recover the data with a professional tools even your hard disk is physically crashed. If you do Google search, you should see the available companies as Google provides result (or ads) considering your location.

In any case, do not use your computer as new data might be overwriten on the lost ones which will make harder to recover the lost data. If you want to continue using your computer, then take image of your hard-disk, so that you can continue using your desktop or if you try to recover the data by yourself, you can attempt to recover data from the image file which will ensure that your PC's file system will not be damaged . You can use [Winhex](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/) to take the image and it also provides data-recovery options. but it is a basic program. More professional (and commercial) tools would be EnCase, Forensic Toolkit, DMZ F.I.R.E., Maresware

But as I said it would save you from a lot trouble if you contact with a company which does data-recovery.